# Show domain user on login screen

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller, login

I've a domain used by both teachers and students. Right now teachers can able to input username and password easily but for the students its quite difficult for them to do the task. I've created two different Organisational Unit for them. I've disabled last logged in user on all machines as well as Ctrl+Del+Alt showing on logon. In order to ease login process for students i want account name to be shown on logon screen can someone please help me on how to add a

> Local Domain User in Student OU to be shown on logon screen so that they can easily login

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How would the PC know to display the correct account name on the correct computer at the correct time?

Comment: How about a same local user in all machines ? Ex. Student on all machine.